# Countries of US addresses showing up as Foreign in some names

Tags: contacts

I have a mailing list of about 1,500 names.  I have imported them into CiviCRM using a CSV spreadsheet file.  The country field for all these names in my spreadsheet are all labeled United States.  A good portion of my addresses after the import into CiviCrm are now listed as another country.  Some show South Africa, etc.  I've tried the import several times to no avail, but my original list is correct.

Any suggestions how to fix this?  Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 3):

(You're relatively new here BTW so welcome!)  It sounds as though your import sheet did not specify a country, but your site allows for multiple countries and thus multiple states/provinces.  Even if the United States is your default country, I've found that the import routine will pick the first country it finds in the list of countries with similar state abbreviations, rather than hitting the correct one.  The workaround to this is pretty simple; include a column for country in your import and populate it with United States (or the appropriate country).

Hope this helps!

Comment: yep exactly the solution we have used and suggested to others for this problem. it can be fun though looking at dbs that others have imported and seeing all their US contacts spread across the globe ;-)